# Upload file with different name

Tags: android, file-upload, multipart

I want to upload images & send with different names.

Send images successfully but with the original name:

```
httpPostuplod = new HttpPost(URL);
MultipartEntity multiPart = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

for (int i = 0; i < imglist.size(); i++) {      
    System.out.println(imglist.get(i));
    File file = new File(imglist.get(i));

    // multiPart.addPart("IMG_"+Constants_Fix.postImgcount+".png", new FileBody(new File(imglist.get(i))));
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/png");

    multiPart.addPart("IMG_"+Constants_Fix.postImgcount+".png",cbFile);

    Constants_Fix.postImgcount++;
}

httpPostuplod.setEntity(multiPart);

HttpResponse resuplod = httpclient.execute(httpPostuplod);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/**
             * Generated Random Number without specifying any range
             */

```
    Random rand = new Random();
            int numNoRange = rand.nextInt();
            String number = String.valueOf(numNoRange);

File imageFile =  new File(path,number+"img.jpg");
```

generate a  Random Number  and append the number to your image name

Comment: then change the name with :  filename+number

Comment: ignore that code .. i just put the code for you to show how to append the image name with the number

Comment: in your code you need to change this line("IMG_"+Constants_Fix.postImgcount+".png",cbFile) ....

Comment: give the random number .. so that u can generate file names with different names right

Comment: means ?? how to generate the number